# Swagger Data Type Model in ImplicitParam with Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-play2

I'm trying to use Swagger to document my REST API. Following this [example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/scala-play2/app/controllers/PetApiController.scala), I annotate the REST Endpoints like this:

```
case class CreateItemRequest(title: String, body: String)

@ApiOperation(value = "Create a new item", httpMethod = "POST", response = classOf[Item])
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(new ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "CreateItemRequest", paramType = "body", name = "body", required = true, allowMultiple = false, value = "The item object to create")))
def create(
          @ApiParam(value = "Hash of the user", required = true)
          @QueryParam("userhash") userhash: String
          )
```

And I was expecting to get "Model" like [image: this] but I get only the String "CreateItemRequest" as Data Type. Not the properties of the case class CreateItemRequest.

Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem :\

Answer (score 9):

You should use the full namespace in the dataType attribute. For example:
`@ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "org.test.CreateItemRequest")`

Answer (score 0):

try to annotate your models with the swagger annotations as well, like shown here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/scala-play2/app/models/Pet.scala

your annotation ApiModel(name="CreateItemRequest") match the annotation @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "CreateItemRequest")

Cheers, Johannes

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this annotation `@JsonAutoDetect` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` before your class and then add `@JsonPropety` for each properties you want to show.

Make sure that in your route definition you call your method like :

```
GET  url   controllers.foo.YourMethod(param: type)
```

More example [here](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/rest-api-documentation-with-swagger/).

Hope this will help you.